# Get total Git LFS size

Tags: bash, ls, git, size

**How can I get total size of Git LFS files?**

I can get a listing of LFS files with `git lfs ls-files --size`:

```
b1d5dd29dd - file1.zip (1.42 GB)
27d3073f43 - file2.zip (120 MB)
cacd6dbfe3 - folder/file3.zip (110.2 MB)
295442cd34 - "folder/(120 MB).zip" (110.2 MB)
680bb2ab19 * test.txt (5 B)
```

Note: [both `-` and `*` are used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36585393).

I can filter to get only the sizes using `git lfs ls-files --size | awk  -F " " '{ print $(NF-1) $NF }' | tr -d '()'`:

```
1.42GB
120MB
110.2MB
110.2MB
5B
```

I don't know if these are powers of 1000 (GB) or 1024 (GiB), so it is fine to assume the larger one (1.00 GB = 1024 MB).

**How can I get the total of 1.88 GiB (`(1.42) * 1024^3 + (120 + 110.2 + 110.2) * 1024^2 + (5) * 1 = 1881648665.48 bytes = 1.88 GiB`)?**

An alternative way of getting total size without parsing the Git equivalent of `ls` is also acceptable, preferably using plain Bash and GNU tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any option specifically to print sizes in bytes rather than human readable sizes however it looks like the `--debug` option does this.   The output of `--debug` is quite different though and according to the man page "the exact format may change at any time" so keep that in mind.

However with the sizes in bytes we can do something like this:

```
git lfs ls-files --debug | awk -F: '$1~/size/{t+=$2}END{printf "Total is: %dGB\n", t/1024/1024/1024}'
```

Here awk will sum up every value of "size" in the `t` variable and after reading all lines it will print out the value of t/1024/1024/1024 or GB, add another /1024 for TB or remove one for MB, etc.

(Note I do not recognize the existence of "metric" data sizes and therefore do not recognize "GiB", "MiB", etc)